# MS Access setting unbound text boxes to Null in Print Preview

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox, print-preview

I recently upgraded computers and, as a result, upgraded my version of Access. With catastrophic results. The new version produces reports that are missing large amounts of data and have If-Then code producing absurd results. In trouble-shooting the issues I quickly found that the unbound text boxes that I've been using as controls for the rest of the form are being reset to Null when switching to Print Preview.

To simplify the problem I built a shiny, new database to avoid any version incompatibility or migration issues. I then made a very basic form that has two text boxes.

Text Box 1 is unbound and is filled by an On Load subroutine that reads:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Me.Text0 = "Yay! Data!"
End Sub
```

Text Box 2 checks to see if the value of Text Box 1 is Null.

```
=IIf(IsNull([Text0]),"Bugger, where did it go?","All good!")
```

When the report is loaded all looks good.

When the view is switched to Print Preview Text Box 1 goes blank and Text Box 2 indicates that the value in Text Box 1 is now Null.

After switching back to Report view, Text Box 1 remains Null. The data is gone and not coming back.

Interestingly, if you open the report in Print Preview mode it all looks fine. I'm guessing that there's a requery or something similar triggered by switching views.

I've tried looking this up but results have been unhelpful answers from a decade or more ago. Can anybody kindly explain to me why MS Access Print Preview insists on eating/dropping/purging my data? And how to get it to quit being pesky.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't help you, but IMHO reports should be designed for Report view OR Print view, not both.

Comment: @Andre Agreed whole-heartedly. Report view is What-You-See-Is-Only-Tangentially-Related-To-What-You-Get. If the control buttons worked in Print Preview I would have no use for it.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the Load event. My guess is that it does not execute when switching views. Why would you need code to populate Text0? Why not expression in ControlSource?

Comment: For this trivial example I don't. This is just to show the problem. For the database that I'm trying to debug there's a lot of formatting that gets done in the VBA code. I might be able to do it via the control source but it'd be a warren of If statements and kludged together text boxes because they only fit so much code.

Comment: Maybe textbox needs to call custom function. Hard to advise without knowing 'real' circumstances. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: *If the control buttons worked in Print Preview* -- then the controls (buttons, text boxes) should be on the form that opens the report. This might be less work than expected, just move the controls and their code, and in the report VBA, replace `Me!` by `frm!` when referencing them. (With `frm` being a form variable set to the controlling form)

Comment: we don't know enough about the code.  given that I would follow either June 7th or Andre's last comments.  Either create a loading form to open the report and pass 
 the openArgs.  If that isn't appropriate then you can create a viewmodel to bind the controls to.  in Access, you can see public functions declared in a code module most anywhere so create set and get functions to simulate properties and bind the report controls to the properties.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. The stripped down database that I created for trying to get this figured has little to no code, all of which is shown in my first post. Everything uses standard issue unadulterated text boxes.

Comment: I've managed to pin this down to a version issue. I placed the test database that I created on the network drive. When I run it on the new computer using Access 365, Print Preview causes the data to be dropped. When I run it on an older computer running Access 2016 everything works fine. So the code works as you'd expect it to in Access 2016 but not Access 365. Is there anywhere that I can post this test database?